# Windows 7 Samba issue

Tags: linux, windows-7, redhat, samba

We have a strange samba issue affecting only one user. Our samba setup is as follow :

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)     - Samba Server

Samba version 3.0.33-3.14.el5                             - Samba version

Domain Controller WIN2008R2 Standard                      - Windows DC

Windows 7 64 bit                                          - Client PCs

User mentioned that he faced this problem after he force shutdown his PC few weeks ago. By right, for all users when we access `\\sambaservername` in windows it will show all the shares in the samba server but for this user once he startup his PC he will not be able to access `\\sambaservername`, Error message

> Windows cannot access `\\sambaservername`

Current workaround to solve the problem :

Try to access one share in `\\sambaservername` for instance `\\sambaservername\sharedfolder1`. But even when doing so, it will first prompt an error in the beginning, error message is as follows

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

user need to enter the credentials again and he can access the share. Thereafter, he will be able to access `\\sambaservername` without any issues. But once he reboots his computer the problem will persists.

Troubleshooting done so far:

1. Ensure the following settings:

   Go to: Control Panel → Administrative Tools → Local Security Policy
   Select: Local Policies → Security Options

   "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" → Send LM & NTLM responses
   "Minimum session security for NTLM SSP" → uncheck: Require 128-bit encryption
2. Advise user to reset his password and try again but problem still persists
3. Tried my account on users' PC, there is no issues. Tried user account on serveral other Windows 7 PC including mine but problem still persists. Windows XP does not have this problem.
4. Ensure that there is no stored crendentials on the windows 7 PC. Checked the credentials manager in Control Panel as well as typing this command `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr`
5. Restart winbindd daemon on samba server but to no avail.

I suspect this is due to some caching issue but not sure where is the issue. Whenever the user has error accessing `\\sambaservername`, the following errors will be logged in the samba server :

```
[2012/10/10 17:10:26, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
[2012/10/10 17:10:27, 1] smbd/sesssetup.c:reply_spnego_kerberos(316)
  Failed to verify incoming ticket with error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE!
```

But after workaround, there will be no more errors. I suspect after reading the article listed below some amendments need to be made to the `\var\samba\cache` directory :

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/getent-passwd-dont-show-ad-groups-and-users-745829/
- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/tdb.html
- http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2010-May/155521.html
- http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2011-March/161912.html
- http://lzeit.blogspot.sg/2009/10/samba-shares-inaccessible-after-power.html

There are several users using the samba server and i would like to solve this problem without any impacts.

I saw the following article :

- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#WINBINDCACHETIME

"winbind offline logon (G) 
This parameter is designed to control whether Winbind should allow to login with the    pam_winbind module using Cached Credentials. **If enabled, winbindd will store user credentials from successful logins encrypted in a local cache.**

Default: winbind offline logon = false

Example: winbind offline logon = true "

Any idea on how to delete the entry for one user in the local cache ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the [`nbtstat -R`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nbtstat) command (which *"purges and reloads the remote cache name table."*) or the `nbtstat -RR` one (which *"sends name release packets to WINs and then starts Refresh."*) can do anything to enforce the kind of refresh you are looking for...

If you want to check out the manual, [look here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940106.aspx)..

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that ntpd is synched with the domain controller.  I had the same problem until today I noticed a 45 min time difference between the offending server and the domain controller.  Once I ran ntpdate it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is usually the result of time drift on either the domain controller, or in your case with only one client having an issue, the connecting client machine. Because Kerberos includes time related parameters in both the authentication server request and the authentication server reply (AS_Req and AS_rep) a wide discrepancy will cause the session token to be rejected.

AS_Req include the Lifetime for the requested token:
AS_REQ = ( PrincipalClient , PrincipalService , IP_list , Lifetime )

AS_Rep includes the DC timestamp and the applied lifetime:
AS_REP = { PrincipalService , Timestamp , Lifetime , SKTGS }

So, if the time variance is outside of the Lifetime, the connection is rejected.

CONJECTURE: I haven't been able to confirm with documentation that lifetime is specified in minutes, but I think it is because I have had a machine that would intermittently work and the only reason I could think of was that it was right on the border of the lifetime.  So for about 30 seconds it would work and then the minute would flip and connections would be rejected.